# WCM Authoring Template fails to apply correctly to existing content, but works with new content

Tags: templates, element, wcm

I have an Authoring Template in WCM that I recently modified, which was originally created by someone else.

I added 2 new elements, an "Option Selection" and a "Short Text" element.

For the option selection I just set it to have 2 radio buttons as choices, and for the short text I set up a "help description" to tell the user what input is expected.

When I tried to "Apply Authoring Template" to content items that were originally created with this AT (using "Add new elements" AND "Copy hidden fields values from Authoring Template") the 2 new elements only partially be applied.

The Option Selection element is shown, but the radio boxes are not. You can't select anything.

The Short Text box shows up as well, but the "help description" does not.

However, if I create a brand new content item using this AT, then it all works correctly; The option selection element has the radio boxes and the short text element has the help description.

Any idea why these things are not coming over correctly when I apply the authoring template to existing content items?? Yet they are working just fine with brand new content items?

I'm using IBM Web Content Management v7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this only happens when you try to apply changes to an authoring template that the content item is already using.

If you change the content item's authoring template, and then change it back to the one that you modified, the elements will be applied correctly.

Not sure if this is how WCM is intended to work, but that's what I've observed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is sort of old, but I've seen this behaviour too.

I noticed if I applied the template, and saved the content item, then tried to edit again, the option selection fields would appear.

Cheers

Comment: More specifically, this can happen if you have the content item open, and then make the template changes and try to apply them.  You should close all content items before making template changes.  Then open, apply, and save.